# Nunit base class with common tests

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using nunit to do some tests for some classes.

There are a couple of operations that are common for all the test classes but require different parameters to work.

So I added the tests in a base class and virtual methods in the base class to provide the parameters.

In the derived test classes I overriden the virtual methods to provide specific parameters for the tests in the base class.

Now my problem is that I want the tests in the base class to be executed only from the derived classes. I am currently using the ignore attribute on the base class to ignore the tests but this causes some warnings when the tests are ran and there is a policy that does not allow me to submit the changes to svn if there are a number of ignored tests.

So how can I run the tests from the base class in the derived classes only without using the ignore attribute on the base class.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should be able to mark your base class as abstract, this will stop nunit running the tests in that class - meaning you no longer need the ignore attribute.

```
namespace MyTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public abstract class BaseTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void CommonTest()
        {

        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass1 : BaseTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void OtherTest1()
        {

        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass2 : BaseTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void OtherTest2()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible, it seems all so simple. How could I have missed it. If it is an abstract class Nunit has no way to directly instantiate it and run the tests.